# "Take a break from" vs. "take a break with"

Tags: prepositions, difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *take a break from* and *take a break with*? For example:

> I'm going to take a break **from**/**with** studying.
>
> It's time to take a break **from**/**with** word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**They are almost opposites**

I am going to take a break from *activity* (or person).

I am going to take a break with *person*.

**Examples**

I hate John. I need to take a break (away) from him and his annoying habits.

I love John. I am going to take a break (together) with him in the countryside

I am going to take a break from work, because I am tired

I am going to take a break with my friends so that we can enjoy each other's company.

I am going to take a break **from** work **with** my friends. We are both tired and will spend a few days together relaxing.